# viewing all changes side-by-side in a single interface in git

Tags: git

`git difftool` launches kdiff3, which has a two-pane view of old and new. But it launches kdiff3 for one file at a time.

```
Viewing (1/1): 'tests/integration/Test.php'
Launch 'kdiff3' [Y/n]: y
```

How do I get git to launch kdiff3 to display **all** uncommitted changes in the whole tree? And difference between two different commits? I have gotten used to such a tool with qbzr's qdiff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Debian(at least Ubuntu) You can use `gitk`. It's preinstalled with GIT I believe. Or `gitg` which for me has nicer interface but you need to install it.

For Windows I recommend [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/)

From all these tools you can do pretty much anything. Compare commits also.

Comment: Gitk can launch external diff tools for uncommitted changes and to compare commits. It can also blame(annotate) files.